Intersection multiplicity of two curves embedded in the projective plane
I encountered the following problem and hope to receive guidance from everyone.
Let $\phi$ maping from $C[x,y]$ into $C[x,y,z]$ turning a polynomial $f(x,y)$ into $F(x,y,z)= z^{deg f}f(x/z,y/z)$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ intersects $g(x,y)$ at $P(a,b)$. Then $F$ and $G$ (images of $f$ and $g$ through the above homomorphism) intersect at $P'(a,b,1)$. Using $Res(f,g,z)$ I have shown that in the case where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in $x$, the number of intersection multiplicity of $f$ and $g$ at $P$ is equal to the number of intersection multiplicity of $F$ and $G$ at $P'$.
However, I am not satisfied with this proof. There is another definition of intersection multiplicity, which is $\nu (f,g,P):=\dim_C O_P/(f,g)$ where $O_P$ is stalk at $P$. So, is it possible prove $\dim_C O_P/(f,g)=\dim_C O_{P'}/(F,G)$ or more strongly, can show whether there exists an isomorphism between those two rings?

$f(x,y)\mapsto z^{\deg f} f(x/z,y/z)$ is not a homomorphism: $x$ and $x^2$ map to $x$ and $x^2$, but $x+x^2$ maps to $xz+x^2$. And $F,G$ are not elements of $O_{P'}$. You have some rather serious misconceptions here. (Also, please fix your formatting, the post is not very readable at the moment.)

sorry, my wrong. $\phi$ just be a map. if f, g go through P(a,b) then F,G also go through P'(a,b,1)

I construct an homomorphism as follows. Let $\rho$ be the compositional homomorphism of $O_P \rightarrow  O_P' \rightarrow
O_P'/(F,G)$. Then $\rho$ is epi and ker $\rho$ =(f,g).
